# MythBuntu installs but doesn't install grub correctly

Tags: ubuntu, grub, mythtv, mythbuntu

I've installed Mythbuntu on my computer but it won't boot anymore, the only thing it does is write:

> Grub stage 1.5
>
> Error 15
>
> file not found...

When I load it with a live-cd and search, there is no file `/boot/grub/` and when I log into the grub console (`sudo grub`) and try to fix it :

```
root (hd0,5)
setup (hd0)
```

It tells me that the files

> /boot/grub/ /grub/

are not found. (Ps: partition 6 is the good one but I've tried them all up and none is working)

Comment: Could you add details of the system's drives+partitions (i.e. the output of `fdisk -l`)? As you didn't mention them I'm assuming there is no RAID or LVM setup on your install. Could it be that you are hitting some sort of limit as to where on the drive the boot partition can be (`lilo` used to have a lot of problems with large drives because of that sort of thing) in which case you might need to have a small `/boot` partition somewhere early on the disk if you don't already have it separate from `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I can't make it work, so I've installed an other distro and now it works, thanks for all you help.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the command:

```
find /boot/grub/stage1
```

to see if you can find it and use

```
root (hd?,?) setup (hd?)
```

where ? is the data that find command retrieve

If it doesn´t works, you can try with your installation cd, open a shell a use:

```
linux rescue
```

and introduce the following commands

```
chroot /mnt/sysimage
grub-install --recheck /dev/hda
exit
exit
```

Comment: find /boot/grub/stage1 display Error 15 file not found

Comment: /mtn/sysimage doesn't exist :(

Comment: If you don´t want to lose a lot of time, try to reinstall everything. It may work :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting the correct partition for `grub` s config file.

I had this error once and ended up being that I had set `5` instead of `6` and I couldn't spot the error right away because *of course, its sda6, so its (hd1,6)!*.
As I had being making a lot of other config edits (it was an Arch install), I missed it.

<sub>I should have put (hd1,5)</sub>

Comment: well I did try hdo0,x (from x=0 to x=9) (I was also pretty piss off...)